# Using Python and Open CV to match images and execute commands in another code

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

So fair warning, I am new to Python. Basically This is a script that communicates to another script. The py script compares stored images to a live feed for a reasonable match to a specific location in the live feed. While the other just interprets the results and sends them to a device.

Most of the time the images are pretty consistent and it will only print once. But some on the other hand, cause it to "flood" the output as it is matching a different similarity in the same defined location. I am trying to figure out the best way to suppress multiple print notifications from that.

This is all there is to the Python side of the code, removing print statements from the Python code remedies the print flood issue, but takes away the only means to know what the state is.

```
import os
import cv2
import time


class GCVWorker:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        self.gcvdata = bytearray(255)

        self.User_defined_event_1 = cv2.imread('Images/Event_Data/xy.png')
        self.User_defined_event_1_b = cv2.imread('Images/Event_Data_b/xy.png')
        self.User_defined_event_2 = cv2.imread('Images/Event_Data/xy.pmg')
        self.User_defined_event_2_b = cv2.imread('Images/Event_Data_b/xy.png')

        self.Found_User_defined_event_1 = True
        self.Found_User_defined_event_1_b = True
        self.Found_User_defined_event_2 = True
        self.Found_User_defined_event_2_b = True
        
    def __del__(self):
        del self.gcvdata
        del self.User_defined_event_1
        del self.User_defined_event_1_b
        del self.User_defined_event_2
        del self.User_defined_event_2_b
        
    def process(self, frame):
        self.gcvdata[0] = False
        self.gcvdata[1] = False

        User_defined_event_1 = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        similar = cv2.norm(self.User_defined_event_1, User_defined_event_1)
        if similar <= 3000.0 and self.User_defined_event_1:
            print('User defined event 1 Detected')
            self.Found_User_defined_event_1 = False
            self.gcvdata[0] = True
        elif similar <= 3000.0 and self.User_defined_event_1_b:
            print('User defined event 1 Detected')
            self.Found_User_defined_event_1_b = False
            self.gcvdata[0] = True
        elif similar <= 3000.0:
            pass
        else:
            self.Found_User_defined_event_1 = True

        User_defined_event_2 = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        similar = cv2.norm(self.User_defined_event_2, User_defined_event_2)
        if similar <= 3000.0 and self.User_defined_event_2:
            print('User defined event 2 Detected')
            self.gcvdata[1] = True
            self.User_defined_event_2_a = False
        elif similar <= 3000.0 and self.User_defined_event_2_b:
            print('User defined event 2 Detected')
            self.gcvdata[1] = True
            self.User_defined_event_2_b = False
        elif similar <= 3000.0:
            pass
        else:
            self.Found_User_defined_event_2 = True
    return frame, self.gcvdata
```

Comment: welcome. your question would benefit from the code being a [mre]. your code currently is just a class definition, no actual execution of anything.

Comment: Basically the python code just compares the images and sends it back to a a device that has defined button presses that will execute depending on the result of the events in the python code being true or false. The self.gcvdata[0], self.gcvdata[1] is the link between python code and the device's code. Basically this is all there is to the python side of things.

Comment: state machine. detection/non-detection is a state. when you analyze a new frame, you check if the state changes. you compare current state and new value, before assigning it. now you can react to state changes. you can react to a detection appearing, or disappearing. -- your code's logic does something that resembles this, but it's too much for me to analyze in passing